# eloquent where has performance issue

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, query-performance

I am using eloquent where has relation in 3 global scopes and these scopes cause a significant performance drop

this query takes about 140 seconds on the server to process!!

this is the globalScopes

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
    
    if ( !auth('admin')->check() ) {
        static::addGlobalScope(new DoesntHaveForbiddenArtistScope());
        static::addGlobalScope('has-artist', function (Builder $builder) {
            $builder->whereHas('artists');
        });
        static::addGlobalScope('has-mp3', function (Builder $builder) {
            $builder->whereHas('mp3s');
        });
    }
}
```

and this is the count query that i saw in telescope

```
from `tracks`
where exists(
        select *
        from `artists`
                 inner join `artist_track`
                            on `artists`.`id` =
                               `artist_track`.`artist_id`
        where `tracks`.`id` = `artist_track`.`track_id`
          and `published` = 1
          and `forbidden` = 0
    )
  and `published` = 1
  and not exists(
        select *
        from `artists`
                 inner join `artist_track`
                            on `artists`.`id` =
                               `artist_track`.`artist_id`
        where `tracks`.`id` = `artist_track`.`track_id`
          and `forbidden` = 1
    )
  and exists(
        select *
        from `artists`
                 inner join `artist_track`
                            on `artists`.`id` =
                               `artist_track`.`artist_id`
        where `tracks`.`id` = `artist_track`.`track_id`
          and `published` = 1
          and `forbidden` = 0
    )
  and exists(
        select *
        from `track_mp3s`
        where `tracks`.`id` = `track_mp3s`.`track_id`
          and `downloaded` = 1
    )
```

is there any what to improve the eloquent query I wrote to speed things up?
I am currently using MySQL indexes that helped a little but 140 sec way too much

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.

Comment: When `JOINing` tables, please qualify each column so we can easily see which table each is in.  For help with performance, it is vital that we know whether `forbidden` is in `artists` or `artist_track`.  Etc.